# Publish feeds using Django

Tags: python, django, rss

I'm publishing a feed from a Django application.

I subclassed django.contrib.syndication.feeds.Feed, everything works fine, except the date that doesn't get published on the feed.

Here's the method I've created on my Feed class

```
def item_pubdate(self, item):
    return item.date
```

this method never gets called....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been banging my head against this one for a while. It seems that the django rss system need a "datetime" object instead of just the date (since it wants a time zone, and the date object doesn't have a time, let alone a time zone...)

I might be wrong though, but it's something that I've found via the error logs.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Feed Class Reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/#feed-class-reference) in the Django documentation, the item_pubdate field is supposed to return a datetime.datetime object.  If item.date is just a DateField and not a DateTimeField, that might be causing the problem.  If that is the case you could change the method to make a datetime and then return that.

```
import datetime
def item_pubdate(self, item):
    return datetime.datetime.combine(item.date, datetime.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how mine is setup, and it is working.

```
class AllFeed(Feed):
    def item_pubdate(self, item):
        return item.date
```